# Reading 2 files into an array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, file, process, struct

How do I read 2 seperate files into my array of structs?
Here's a small piece of the code

```
struct NameRecord {
    char name[31];
    int year;
    int frequency;
};
```

```
fp = fopen("malebabynames.csv", "r");

while(3 == fscanf(fp,"%d,%[^,],%d", 
                  &records[currSize].year, records[currSize].name,
                  &records[currSize].frequency)) {
  currSize++;
}

fclose(fp);
```

Comment: Please be a bit more specific. Do you want to read in one file after another? Do the files contain the same content/structure? What troubles are you running into?

Comment: I want to read one after another yes, and they contain different content but have the same structure

Answer (score 1):

Open second file the same way you opened the first file:

`FILE *fp2 = fopen("[filename]", "r");`

And read the same way you do for first file using `fscanf`.